# Unity - RageTools Performance

Tags: unity, 2d

Has anyone used RageTools for Unity? What do you know about the performance? Is it more performant than using raster, for example with "puppet 2d" or the other way?
I'm developing mobile games, so performance is very important for me.
Thank you!